# Odoo upload and read file/read file from console

Tags: python, file, upload, base64, odoo

odoo developers!
I need your help. I have to upload the file in my custom model.
I have button and field. And the problem with the method. I've read some advices, there guys speak about base64 decode/encode and stringIO

How can I read that file is imported, that python/browser see him from console, odoo.log etc, for example?

Comment: Your question is barely understandable, do you mean upload a file into odoo?

Comment: @Eric yes, i have button and field, i can upload file, but i need the method which can tell that file is uploaded